# android sherlock setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled not working and how to set custom target?

Tags: java, android

I've called setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and the arrow is showing, but it goes no where, I'd also like to manually set the link/target of the button to go to a custom location.

How can I specify a custom location? Thankyou.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock like the title says, you should instead use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Either way, to handle the click, you have to make a case for `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Eg:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //do your own thing here
        return true;
    default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }
}
```

Also, by custom location, I don't know what you mean, you can certainly make a `new Intent()` to do *something*.

However, to keep things consistent with the Android guidelines, you *should* be using the Up icon to actually go up.

Comment: To add to "A-C" nice answer.  Most of the time you will put: "this.finish()" where he has "//do your own thing here"

Comment: @CoreyScott keyword *most*, but keep in mind the documentation for [ancestral navigation does say not to use it](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html). I personally use `NavUtils` since it saves some lines and it complies with the guidelines :-)